What does this message from Xoom mean?
My friend in the US sent me some money using a money transfer service called Xoom. I am supposed to receive the money to my mobile wallet. The transfer has taken more than a week so I decided to email Xoom to update me on the status of the transaction but this is the email they keep replying with:

We're sorry, but the email address used to contact us is different than the one registered to your Xoom account. Please send us an email from the address we have on file or if you are the recipient, please have your sender to contact us with questions and we'll be happy to assist.

Sometimes they say Xoom account and some other time they say Xoom transaction.

We're sorry, but the email address used to contact us is different than the one registered to your Xoom transaction. If you're the recipient, please inform your sender to contact us for further assistance.

From that email, I know the transaction is there but am not sure if it's been canceled or delayed for unknown reasons. The sender is offline and unreachable, does that message confirm the transaction is inbound or what does it mean because its taken far too long.

This sounds like a scam. Have you ever met that friend? Why would they be transferring anything to you?

@littleadv, yes I know him, we met on Christianity Stack Exchange and he sent me some money in the past which I received via Xoom. But this time round it's taken longer compared to last time. Last time he sent on a Sunday evening and it arrived on a Thursday morning. This time he sent it on Friday last week but up to now haven't received anything

@DongLi Unfortunately, these days, "yes I know him, we met on [an online place]" is not something to rely on. It is vastly more likely than not that the first money wasn't the sender's in the first place (sent from another victim's account).

@TripeHound, no he is a born-again Christian, and his name was on the confirmation message I received from my local mobile money service provider. I know what he does for a living and he has never asked me to make any payment to his accounts or anything.

You don't confirm that you are emailing from the same account that's on the Xoom account. Have you double-checked that?

@mkennedy, I am the recipient, so they expect an email from the sender, maybe that's why

"He is a born again Christian" => he SAYS he is a born-again Christian. "I know what he does for a living" => you know what he SAYS he does for a living. You may need to adjust your gullibility filter thresholds. Alternatively, I am a Nigerian prince and I have a great opportunity for you...

@Vicky, what great opportunity? Am just curious.

@Vicky, if you are talking about the online scams people encounter, me and this person we are different, we hold discussions on Bible doctrines, we pray together and we both have struggles that unite us in a common hope in Christ. He is a principled Christian who has never lied about anything up to now.

Xoom is legit. They are part of Pay Pal. Doesn't sound like a scam for there part. See https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/what-is-xoom-and-how-does-it-work-help228

@DongLi I am not a Nigerian prince. I do not have an opportunity for you. My point was that anyone can claim to be anything online and you should not be so willing to believe everything anyone tells you. Even if this particular event is not a scam, this is general good life advice.

Discussions of biblical doctrine do not mean that the person is honest, it just means that they can talk a good line. People who believe that a Christian must be honest, or that anybody who can discuss Christianity must be a Christian, are among the easiest targets for a scammer. Get out of that habit. You do not know that he has not lied about anything up to now, you only know that you haven't caught him. Perhaps because you haven't tried. Compassion is a great thing, but caution is necessary or you will be taken advantage of.

Xoom has the transaction associated with an e-mail address. There message means that this e-mail address is different from the one you send your inquiry from and hence they can't give you any information. This is perfectly normal security behavior.
Most likely the transaction is associated with the e-mail address of your friend, so they need to  send the inquiry or, simpler, just log into their account.
If you are lucky, the transaction is also associated with the e-mail address of the recipient (i.e. yours). That could have been provided by the sender or associated with the recipient's Xoom account (if you have one).
You could try to sort this out, but by far the simplest way would be to ask your friend to check the transaction status on their Xoom account.

It means exactly what it says.
The message is addressed to you, telling you that you are sending your inquiry from an email account that they are not aware of. Fix your mailer to send from the account they know of, or log in and fix your profile so they know the account that you want to send from is associated with your account at Xoom.

what do they mean with the email address they have on file? Does it mean my email address is not registered with them and hence they cannot discuss any transaction with me?

you can see they are comparing my email address with another one that's on file and they note a discrepancy, why would they compare my email address with another when am the recipient because I do not have an account with Xoom

You may need an account with Xoom to communicate with their help desk. If you really don't have one, create one, then try contacting them again. Michael search services, they are not going to want to speak to you unless they have been able to verify your identity.

but why mention a Xoom transaction, I filled my names in the contact form and maybe they searched it in their system and found a transaction associated with my name but then they see the email address that sent the transaction to be that of the sender and not mine so they advise me to contact the sender who can instead email them?

You're the one who said your friend initiated a Xoom transaction. If it didn't go through, you or they must contact Xoom to resolve it, and they must know that the person contacting them is legitimately involved in the transaction. That is all anyone except the support desk can tell you.

yes my friend initiated the transfer but it didn't go through, unfortunately xoom help desk cannot discuss transaction details with the recipient, it is their policy that is why they advise you to contact them through the sender

So why haven't you asked the sender to contact them?

@Vicky, I have, we do talk on Google Chat, he seems to be very busy as he is working on several projects. I know he is honest and this can be validated with the original aid he sent among other things he has entrusted me with. You mentioned you are a Nigerian prince, or that is just an analogy to meeting someone online?

Nigerian prince: a reference to one of the oldest documented scams on the internet. In fact, the scam predates the internet, but some Nigerian scammers have made a major operation out of it.

If your friend needs to talk to them, have your friend talk to them. Either wait for your friends to do it, or stop waiting, and just trust that it will get straightened out eventually, or accept that it may not get straightened out in the money may not arrive and if this isn't a scam, you probably haven't lost anything. If your friend is unreliable, but you still believe their trustworthy, that's something you need to work out with them.

"He is very busy working on several projects" is classic scammer tactic too. @DongLi I suggest you read up about pig butchering scams, eg here https://www.finra.org/investors/insights/pig-butchering-scams and realise that it's a common tactic for scammers to send some initial money (often coming from a stolen or hacked account) to build your trust and get you on the hook, so that when they eventually ask you to invest, or to pay some fees or taxes to access the money they have supposedly sent you, you will be less suspicious.
